# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Socket TCP/IP, WebSockets y Request HTTP?

Tags: socket, tcpip, websocket

Tengo una duda respecto a estos tres protocolos de transmisión de datos en Internet. Se que los **sockets TCP/IP** son una manera de comunicación a bajo nivel que utiliza la capa de transporte para realizar la transmisión de datos y los manejo muy bien.

Pero los **WebSockets** y los **Request HTTP**, entiendo que se construyen sobre la capa de aplicación y por los ejemplos que he visto ambos son muy parecidos en cuanto su a forma.

¿Estoy en lo correcto?
¿Los WebSockets son una mejora de Request HTTP o son lo mismo?
¿En que casos es mejor usar WebSockets que un Request HTTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De manera sencilla: Sockets TCP son conexiones a muy bajo nivel. Puedes verlo como la conexión física entre dos equipos. Cuando estableces un socket TCP puedes enviar y recibir datos de manera síncrona o asíncrona, dependiendo del protocolo que utilices a partir de ese momento.

HTTP es un protocolo síncrono que va sobre TCP. Una petición de HTTP se hace a través de un socket TCP (y la respuesta viaja por el mismo socket).

Web Sockets es un protocolo que va sobre HTTP. Una conexión de web socket se hace a través de un socket TCP, usando el protocolo HTTP inicialmente.

Comment: Gracias, el último párrafo aclaró mi duda :)

Comment: @Hector todo esto que esta escrito aquí es sólo un resumen de mi respuesta excepto que no te dice nada de websockets ni porque fué necesaria su creación.

Comment: @devconcept el tema es que yo no pregunté porque fue necesaria su creación, solo necesitaba saber cual era la relación entre WS y HTTP... creo que esta respuesta me aclara mas la duda, pero tu respuesta tambien es de mucha ayuda por eso tienes +3 :) aveces muchas palabras confunden mas que aclarar ;)

Answer (score 4):

Los [sockets TPC/IP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_de_Internet) son lo que hace posible la arquitectura cliente-servidor, aunque no se limitan a eso. En realidad se involucran en todo tipo de comunicación ya que son el mecanismo para la entrega de paquetes de datos entre computadoras.

> Un socket queda definido por un par de direcciones IP local y remota, un protocolo de transporte y un par de números de puerto local y remoto.

O sea que teniendo las direcciones IP y los puertos aun puedes escoger que protocolo de transporte quieres usar. El protocolo de transporte puede ser cualquiera de los que pertenezca a la [capa de transporte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capa_de_transporte) o capa 4. El TCP se encuentra ubicado en esta capa y el protocolo IP se encuentra en la capa 3[<sup>1</sup>](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_comunicaciones). Como puedes ver todo esto es a muy bajo nivel ya que el HTTP se encuentra en la capa 7, la capa de aplicación, muy por encima de los sockets.

Básicamente no puedes comparar las peticiones HTTP con los sockets ya que el primero es una especialización del segundo.

En cuanto a las [peticiones HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) y [Websockets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) los dos **pueden** realizarse usando el protocolo HTTP pero son protocolos diferentes[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.7).

> El protocolo WebSocket es un protocolo basado en TCP independiente. Su única relación con HTTP es que el handshake es interpretado por servers HTTP como una petición de Actualización.

Una de las razones por la que se escogió que fuera así es porque normalmente los proxys bloquean todo lo que no se transmite por el puerto 80, el puerto por defecto que usa el HTTP. Cuando el cliente (o navegador por lo general) detecta que hay un proxy usa el método HTTP CONNECT para crear una conexión persistente, de lo contrario usa `ws://` o `wss://` para conectarse con el servidor. Las conexiones con `ws://` y `wss://` se establecen en el puerto 80 y 443 respectivamente, exactamente el mismo puerto que el `http://` y `https://`

Los websockets son necesarios ya que el protocolo http fue diseñado desde un principio para no [preservar estado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sin_estado) entre peticiones (es stateless). ¿Que significa esto? Que cuando haces una petición a un servidor y acto seguido mandas otra, este no es capaz de darse cuenta que las dos tienen relación. Normalmente se usan cookies, javascript y código en el servidor para que este entienda que información esta relacionada, pero en sí el protocolo http no tiene nada que ver con eso. Este sólo dicta que cada petición sea autosuficiente como para que el server pueda responderle, identificando solamente cada par "petición/respuesta". Esta es uno de los puntos mas fuertes del protocolo ya que ha permitido crear múltiples formas se comunicación cliente-servidor como [REST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) y [SOAP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Object_Access_Protocol) muy diferentes entre sí.

Algunos tipos de comunicación como por ejemplo un chat requiren que la fuente sea siempre la misma y sea posible saber por ejemplo si se perdió la conexión o se cambió su estado. Mirando las condiciones anteriores del protocolo es un poco complicado lograrlo (aunque no imposible) y de ahí la necesidad de un protocolo como websockets para poder establecer un **túnel estable de comunicación** entre dos partes. Ten en cuenta que para que la comunicación pueda establecerse **ambas partes deben soportar websockets** por lo que la mayoría de los frameworks de hoy en día permiten hacer fallback a peticiónes HTTP si websocket no está soportado.

Algunas formas de sustituir websockets con peticiones HTTP inlcuyen

[Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events): Básicamente una petición http que no termina y en la que ambas partes mandan información (ya que la parte de la respuesta sólo termina cuando se cierra la conexión).

[Long Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-do-i-implement-basic-long-polling): Técnica en la que se envían constantemente peticiones/respuesta a intervalos regulares para que ambas partes actualizen el estado de la conexión y se pasen mensajes. Si una de las partes deja de responder se considera la conexión perdida.

[Comet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet): Conjunto de técnicas que permiten mantener conexión estable usando  tecnología PUSH y otras técnicas http.

Lee también [What are long polling websockets server sent events sse and comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Algunos frameworks que implementan websockets:

- [socket.io](http://socket.io): Node.js(javascript)
- [SignalR](http://signalr.net): C#
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/): Python
- [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/): Php
- [Java-WebSocket](http://java-websocket.org/): Java

Nota: La forma del protocolo de red puede ser tan variada que llegó a inventarse el [IP sobre palomas mensajeras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_sobre_palomas_mensajeras) que se encuentra definido en el [rfc2549](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2549) :P

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero algunos párrafos parecen una traducción que no se entiende muy bien.

Comment: @Hector podrías ser más especifico a que te refieres con una traducción? Todos los artículos referenciados estan en español excepto la referencia al post de StackOverflow

Comment: El texto no responde completamente mis preguntas y algunos párrafos no tienen mucha semántica por lo que no se entiende que es lo que quieres decir o para que mencionas esa información. De todos modos te di +1

Comment: @Hector Mi objetivo es que la respuesta sea clara. Si me puedes indicar que es lo que ha quedado sin responder y edito la pregunta y explico mejor